# Using LinkedIn API without OAuth

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

I use a application to automate posting updates from the site. Can I use the LinkedIn API without connecting OAuth libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You need OAuth libraries to perform various actions with a user-Linkedin account. There're libraries for linkedin easier than others, it depends on the programming language.